# Filtering patient data - how to return bool/string for patients taking two different medications?

Tags: r, filter

I have a very large data set that contains patient-level information on drug names. I am wanting to find patients that are taking certain combinations of drugs but I am having difficulties finding a simple method without creating two subset dataframes and mapping them back to the original dataframe using R.

Here is a fake patient dataframe in R

```
df <- data.frame(pt_id=["p1","p2","p3","p4","p1","p2","p3","p4"],
                 drug=["d1","d1","d1","d1","d2","d2","d3","d3"])
show(df)
##      pt_id     drug
## 1       p1       d1
## 2       p2       d1
## 3       p3       d1    
## 4       p4       d1
## 5       p1       d2
## 6       p2       d2  
## 7       p3       d3
## 8       p4       d3
```

How do I get the following?

```
##      pt_id     drug   drug_combo
## 1       p1       d1         TRUE
## 2       p2       d1         TRUE
## 3       p3       d1        FALSE
## 4       p4       d1        FALSE
## 5       p1       d2         TRUE
## 6       p2       d2         TRUE
## 7       p3       d3        FALSE
## 8       p4       d3        FALSE
```

Where only patients taking "d1" and "d2" (i.e. "p1" and "p2" in this example) are returned TRUE or a per-specified string like "on_d1_d2"

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This checks if both `"d1"` and `"d2"` are present for `pt_id`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(pt_id) %>% mutate(drug_combo = all(c('d1', 'd2') %in% drug))

#  pt_id drug  drug_combo
#  <chr> <chr> <lgl>     
#1 p1    d1    TRUE      
#2 p2    d1    TRUE      
#3 p3    d1    FALSE     
#4 p4    d1    FALSE     
#5 p1    d2    TRUE      
#6 p2    d2    TRUE      
#7 p3    d3    FALSE     
#8 p4    d3    FALSE
```

You can also do this in base R :

```
df$drug_combo <- with(df,ave(drug, pt_id, FUN = function(x) 
                      all(c('d1', 'd2') %in% x)))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, drug_combo := all(c('d1', 'd2') %in% drug), pt_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(pt_id) %>%
   mutate(drug_combo = sum(c('d1', 'd2') %in% drug) == 2)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   pt_id [4]
#  pt_id drug  drug_combo
#  <chr> <chr> <lgl>     
#1 p1    d1    TRUE      
#2 p2    d1    TRUE      
#3 p3    d1    FALSE     
#4 p4    d1    FALSE     
#5 p1    d2    TRUE      
#6 p2    d2    TRUE      
#7 p3    d3    FALSE     
#8 p4    d3    FALSE
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, drug_combo := sum(c('d1', 'd2') %in% drug) == 2, pt_id]
```